# How to switch on a String in UiPath?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity, uipath-api

The UiPath Switch Activity defaults to the int32 data type, so you can easily add case statements based on a whole number, integer value. But if you attempt do use a String as the expression, the activity fails.

So how do you create a String switch activity in UiPath Studio?

Answer (score 5):

While the expression type for a [UiPath switch activity](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/example-uipath-switch-activity-conditional-explained-tutorial) defaults to int32, not String, it can be easily changed by opening the Properties tab in UiPath Studio and clicking the drop-down box associated with the TypeArgument attribute.

### UiPath String Switch Property

In the UiPath Switch's TypeArgument field, you can set the expression type to `String`, `Object`, `DataTable`, `Array of [T]` and any other data type you can access through the `Browse for Types` wizard.

[image: UiPath Switch with String]

### String, Switch, Cases and Double Qoutes

One interesting aspect of the case statements in a UiPath String switch is the fact that the matching field does not need to be in double quotes. Every other place you reference a String in UiPath, it must be in double quotes. The [UiPath string switch](https://youtu.be/HswobQMeyHU) activity seems to be one of the few places where the double-quotes requirement disappears. In fact, if you add double quotes, it likely won't work as intended.